# Family of analytic function in the unit disk problem

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving

> We denote by $D$ the open unit disk and consider the family 
>   $$\mathcal{F}=\{f: D\to D, f \text{ is analytic and } f'(0)=\tfrac{1}{2}\}.$$
>   Prove that there is a function $g\in \mathcal{F}$ such that 
>   $$|g(0)|=\sup\{|f(0)|: f\in\mathcal{F}\}$$

By Pick's theorem, 
$$|f'(0)|\leq \frac{1-|f(0)|^2}{1-0} \Leftrightarrow |f(0)|\leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$$
So, we want to find $g\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $|g(0)|=\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $g'(0)=\tfrac{1}{2}$. The function 
$$g(z)=\frac{z-\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{1-\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}z}$$
satisfied what we want.

Is it correct? Is there a way to solve the problem without finding $g$ explicit?

Comment: I did not check whether the derivative of your function does what it should do, but it seems right to me. A more general tool which could be applied here, Montel's Theorem. In this case this might not be necessary as the derivative of the functions is prescribed, but if we have only a bound on the derivative it might be good to use Montel, see for example the proof of Riemann's mapping theorem.

Comment: I've studied Montel's theorem, but I don't see what have to do with the problem. Could you be more specific?

Comment: First of all, you know that the supremum is finite, let's call it $m$. As it is a supremum, there exists a sequence $(f_n)$ such that $f_n(0)\to m$. By Montel, this sequence has a compactly convergent subsequence and this limit function does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a normal families argument: There exists a sequence $f_n$ in $\mathcal F$ such that

$$|f_n(0)| > (1-1/n)\sup_{f\in \mathcal F} |f(0)|.$$

Because the $f_n$ are uniformly bounded, there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ converging uniformly on compact subsets of $D$ to some $g$ analytic on $D.$ Because $f_{n_k}'$ also converges uniformly on compact subsets of $D$ to $g',$ $g$ has the desired properties.